# Is there any limitation on the number of dependent packages we can create with one main 2GP package?

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, 2gp

I have created 2GP managed package and now we are looking for to create a dependent package. So, I would like to know if there any limitation of how many dependent package we can create with same 2GP managed package.

Main 2GP Package

- dependent package 1
- dependent package 2
- dependent package 3
- dependent package 4
- Any limitation here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no documented technical limits that I'm aware of. You'll want to consider things like security reviews, how long it may take to install many dependencies, etc.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @sfdcfox, there are no explicitly documented limits on the number of dependent packages, and where packages are "verified" - i.e. go through security review - you find that this means certain metadata constraints are relaxed to an extent. However, there are ultimate limits on things like number of custom objects across all installed packages and in the subscriber org.

It is definitely worth considering that package installations are sequential - you cannot install two or more concurrently on an org, so without package bundles (a future feature) it could take a long time to  finish installing all the packages.

Regarding security reviews, note that where multiple packages share the same namespace, Salesforce allow up to 4 of them to be covered by a single security review fee payment - according to a statement made by Vivek Chawla during a partner AMA session. I can't find this publicly documented though. Still, it will take more time and effort to get these individual packages through these separate reviews.